# router-outlet is not a known element in multi module app

Tags: angular, router-outlet

Following is my code error is router-element is not a known element. Attached are screenshots of code:

App routing Module

[image]

App module

[image]

App compoent.ts

[image]

App compoent.html

[image]

Comment: You should consider pasting code instead of images. This makes it easier to see the issue and post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should import  `ProductCardComponent` and `LoginComponent` to `app.module.ts` and add
`ProductCardComponent` and `LoginComponent` under `declarations:[]`